# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.setParser

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

Im trying to get accesstoken from google+ authorization. I'm getting following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.setParser(Lcom/google/api/client/util/ObjectParser;)V
    com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:297)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
    com.Servlet.OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.exchangeCodeForAccessAndRefreshTokens(OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.java:152)
    com.Servlet.OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.doGet(OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.java:87)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Following are api's im using :

```
google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
```

Let me know where exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The method setParser isn't recognized. That's maybe related to the version of jars you are using. Try to upgrade to 1.20.0 version. (Verfiy your classpath as well)